# Python Smtplib BCC issue?

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

I wonder anyone can assist on this.

I have this python code which can send email.

```
import smtplib
import string
import sys
import os

fromaddr = 'first-email@gmail.com'

toaddr = 'second-email@gmail.com'
cc = []
bcc = ['third-email@gmail.com', 'forth-email@gmail.com']
subject = 'This is a test email'

msg = string.join((
    'From: %s' % fromaddr,
    'To: %s' % toaddr,
    'CC: %s' % ', '.join(cc),
    'BCC: %s' % ', '.join(bcc),
    'Subject: %s' % subject, '',
    'hello world'
), '\r\n')

print msg

toaddrs = [toaddr] + cc + bcc

print toaddrs

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.googlemail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login('my_gmail_account','my_gmail_password')
server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddrs,msg)
server.quit()
```

The problem I have is for those who I bcc'ed i.e. third-email@gmail.com and forth-email@gmail.com, they could see who's inside the bcc'd list.

Example,

```
From : first-email@gmail.com
To : second-email@gmail.com
Bcc : third-email@gmail.com,forth-email@gmail.com
```

This is not the right format.

I am expecting the results should be like this.

a. For second-email@gmail.com user

this person should see this

```
From : first-email@gmail.com
To : second-email@gmail.com
Bcc : this is hidden
```

b. For third-email@gmail.com user

this person should see this

```
From : first-email@gmail.com
To : second-email@gmail.com
Bcc : third-email@gmail.com
```

c. For forth-email@gmail.com user

this person should see this

```
From : first-email@gmail.com
To : second-email@gmail.com
Bcc : forth-email@gmail.com
```

Any way to enhance my python smtplib codes to achieve the above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do some coding logic before creating you msg string . Like if person not in Bcc list hide it .if person is in Bcc list append only his name . After create you msg string . I hope this will solve the purpose

Comment: The concern i have to add the logic checking as there's a high possibility that the To (second-email@gmail.com) may receive duplicate emails.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the BCC header, but keep the bcc recipients in `toaddrs`. The bcc recipients will all receive the email, but the email clients won't display them as recipients.

Answer (score 1):

the `sendmail` method from python's `smtplib` module does not honor rfc 822 regarding the bcc header. Instead, it just parses a bunch of text and sends all of it, including bcc, to everyone in to, cc, and bcc. If you can upgrade to python3, python3's `smtplib` includes a method, `send_message`, which will handle bcc headers correctly.